# Pandas: how to identify the values in a column of a dataframe and do some math operations

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I want to do operations, such that I produce something like this:

[image]

In other words, if the values in Name are in the 'first_list', I want to multiply the 'Values' by two. If they are in the 'second_list', I want to multiply them  by 0.5. If they are not in either (for Nick and Nicky), do not do anything.

This is what I have:

```
first_list = ['John', 'James', 'Julius', 'Alex']
second_list = ['Lilly', 'Alexis', 'Becly']
if df['Name'].isin(first_list).any():
    df['New Values'] = df['Values'] * 2
elif df['Name'].isin(second_list).any():
    df['New Values'] = df['Values'] * 0.5
```

But its' not doing the multiplication as I want. Instead, it gives me: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `np.where` and `isin`:

```
df['New Value'] = (np.where(df.Name.isin(first_list),
                            df.Values*2,
                            np.where(df.Name.isin(second_list),
                                     df.Values*.5,
                                     df.Values)))
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Lily','Alexis','Becky','James','Julian','Alex','Nick','Nicky'],'Values':[50,100,30,60,40,20,80,25,46]})

first_list = ['John','James','Julius','Alex']
second_list = ['Lily','Alexis','Becky']
```

Output:

```
     Name  Values  New Value
0    John      50      100.0
1    Lily     100       50.0
2  Alexis      30       15.0
3   Becky      60       30.0
4   James      40       80.0
5  Julian      20       20.0
6    Alex      80      160.0
7    Nick      25       25.0
8   Nicky      46       46.0
```

Comment: Have a great day!